# How to regroup the list of data.frame and export as `csv` into distinctive folder?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, dplyr

I used `bind_rows` to merge data.frame in two different lists, and I proceed to split each by threshold, then export the result as `csv` files. So far, everything is good except all exported `csv` files goes to one default folder. I want to ensure the list of data.frame can be assigned to a distinctive folder for file bar (i.e, file bar refer to name of data.frame `hue`, `ack`, `ken`), instead of putting all `csv` files into one place (for the sake of easy to browse the output for each file bar). How can I make this happen? Is that possible to assign a list of data.frame into a distinctive folder for file bar and proceed writing as `csv`? Any idea?

Here is minimal example data.frame that I want to work with:

```
Positive <- list(
    hue = data.frame( begin=seq(1, by=6, len=20), end=seq(4, by=6, len=20), pos.score=sample(30, 20)),
    ack = data.frame( begin=seq(3, by=9, len=15), end=seq(6, by=9, len=15), pos.score=sample(28, 15)),
    ken = data.frame( begin=seq(6, by=8, len=18), end=seq(11, by=8, len=18), pos.score=sample(22, 18))
)

Negative <- list(
    hue = data.frame( begin=seq(9, by=12, len=30), end=seq(14, by=12, len=30), pos.score=sample(35, 30)),
    ack = data.frame( begin=seq(13, by=10, len=20), end=seq(19, by=10, len=20), pos.score=sample(34, 20)),
    ken = data.frame( begin=seq(23, by=11, len=24), end=seq(31, by=11, len=24), pos.score=sample(27, 24))
)
```

Here is the solution for categorizing data:

```
res <- bind_rows(c(positive = Positive,
                   negative = Negative), .id = "id") %>%
    separate(id, c("status", "Candidate")) %>%
    mutate(TF = ifelse(pos.score >= 18,
                                   "true", "false")) %>%
    split(list(.$Candidate, .$TF, .$status))

exportME <- mapply(write.csv, res, paste0(names(res), ".csv"))
```

I want to figure out `exportMe` can be placed on a different folder for file bar. Before I hit `exportMe`, the code must know how to distribute list of data.frame into the desired folder and export as `csv`. Is there any clever way to do this? Any programmatic, dynamic way to get this done?

In my desired output, each folder can be named as `hue`, `ack`, `ken`, where each folder has following structure:

```
xx.true.positive.csv
xx.true.negative.csv
xx.false.positive.csv
xx.false.nagative.csv
```

How can I make this happen? Is there any smart way to do this? How can I achieve me desired output? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you already have three folders called hue, ack and ken.
If you don't have them, you can create first:

- get the folders names

  `dir_names <- gsub("\\..+","",names(res)) %>% unique()`

  `> dir_names
  [1] "ack" "hue" "ken"`
- then create the folders using dir.create

  `walk(dir_names,dir.create)`

THEN, you can save the csv files in each one accordingly:

```
purrr::walk2(res,names(res),
      function(x,y) 
        write.csv(x,paste0(gsub("\\..+","",y),"/",y,".csv")))
```

- You pass res, and names(res) as x,y
- `gsub("\\..+","",y)` extracts the string before the first period *(i.e. folder name)*, for example:

`> gsub("\\..+","","ack.false.negative")
[1] "ack`

- the result is used in paste0, to form the path of the file.

`"ack/ack.false.negative.csv"`

Comment: you misunderstand me, I don't create `hue`, `ack`, `ken` ,  I want to create them by code in a programmatic way, then proceed writing as `csv`.  Is that doable?

Comment: Please check the edited answer, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, works well to me. Is that possible to use pipe operator to connect each step, try to minimize the code body (to make all code line as small and elegant)? BTW, this is nice work, appreciated.

Comment: You can certainly use :

gsub("\\..+","",names(res)) %>% unique() %>% walk(dir.create)

What do you mean by rename the folder name by preference?

Comment: I just edited the comment. Why we use `walk`, `walk2`? what's the difference? Is that possible to make above solution even smaller? Thank you

Comment: walk() takes one arguments, while walk2() takes two.